# C++ VS2010 using namespace concurrency; No namespace with that name

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, header, namespaces

I tried to follow the instructions on 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/vstudio/dd728073.aspx

I am using VS2010.

I added the following lines to my CPP file:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <ppl.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <random>

using namespace concurrency;
```

But then the compiler tells me "Error C2871: 'concurrency': No namespace with that name exists.'"

Does anybody see what I did wrong?
Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Great, in VS2010 it has to be

```
using namespace Concurrency;
```

instead.